# UK with ACRO record deletion

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I am from India and during my first stay in UK I was arrested on false charges and was released the next day with no further action taken and no conviction when I was found innocent. I made an application to ACRO record deletion and they accepted my application and removed my records from PNC. I want to travel to UK again and what should I answer in my visa application questions "An arrest or charge for which you are currently on trial or awaiting trial", "A caution, warning, reprimand or other penalty" If  I say no, will the UK immigration cancel my visa?

Comment: With immigration it is better be overly cautious, say yes, join your police record, and explain further (if you have papers from your release as innocent, I'd join them even) either in the box under the question or in a cover letter.

Comment: I generally agree with Nicolas that when in doubt, it es better to reveal too much than leaving out potentially relevant information. In this case, as you describe the incident, I can't however see how it can be relevant for the questions asked. You are not 'on trial or awaiting trial' and you have not been issued 'a caution, warning, reprimand or other penalty'.

Comment: I agree with @Tor-EinarJarnbjo on this. The question is very specific and neither of the situations mentioned here fit yours. You were released without being charged.

Comment: Depends how risk averse you are. Clearly answering *Yes* to either question is not appropriate given the situation you describe. However, if you’re worried about it you could answer *no* and explain further in a comments box and/or in a covering letter.